# Retrieve an image from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am able to successfully save my image in user defaults as I use my app and retrieve it just fine but am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve it in a simple via init().  In my example it will returns the AppValue.avatar (my default image) but won't return the stored image.  It can't find the previously stored image so it substitutes my default image it fails because I have UIImage in the published variable.  I think it must have to be retrieved as data but if I change UIImage in the init() to Data Xcode is not happy.

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var avatar: UIImage {
        didSet {
            /// Convert to data using .pngData() on the image so it will store.  It won't take the UIImage straight up.
            let pngRepresentation = avatar.pngData()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(pngRepresentation, forKey: "avatar")
            printSave(forKey: "avatar", value: avatar)
        }
    }
    init() {
        self.avatar = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "avatar") as? UIImage ?? AppValue.avatar 
    }

}
```

Comment: Btw you shouldn't save images in UserDefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a matter of keeping mental track of what type a thing is.

You saved the image as its `pngData` (correctly). This is not a UIImage; it is a Data. Your `pngRepresentation`, which is what gets saved, is a Data.

Hence when you retrieve the image and say `as? UIImage`, that test fails. It is not a UIImage. It's a Data.

Therefore, fetch `data(forKey:)` (or say `as? Data` instead of `as? UIImage`). Now you have the Data. then call `UIImage.init(data:)` to retrieve the image.

Comment: so this ```self.avatar = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "avatar") as? UIImage ?? AppValue.avatar``` gives me "Cast from 'Data?' to unrelated type 'UIImage' always fails"  Not sure how to work in the UIImage.init(data:) in my init statement to convert the Data and return it?